# Starting a node from an archive data downloaded from TezosShots gives "invalid argument" if data-dir is an external drive

Tags: node, archive-node

I am trying to run a node from a Linux Ubuntu VM on a Windows 10 machine. The two OS are connected via a shared folder (which is on my F: drive).

I downloaded context and store folders through tezosshots.com and set my config.json like this:

```
{ "data-dir": "/media/tz/.tezos-node/", "shell": {"history_mode": "archive"},  "p2p": { "listen-addr": "[::]:9732" } }
```

But when I run the node I get this:

```
./tezos-node run
Oct 28 21:18:26 - node.main: Starting the Tezos node...
Oct 28 21:18:26 - node.main: No local peer discovery.
Oct 28 21:18:26 - node.main: Peer's global id: idtxxxxxxxxxum8
Oct 28 21:18:26 - main: shell-node initialization: bootstrapping
Oct 28 21:18:26 - main: shell-node initialization: p2p_maintain_started
tezos-node: Error:
              Invalid argument
```

Edit: identity generation gives no error.

Comment: `Context` and `Store` Folders are in `/media/tz/.tezos-node/` ?
Does the `identity.json` appear at `/media/tz/.tezos-node/`  ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Does your node run normally when running it without the downloaded `context` and `store` folders (i.e. when trying to bootstrapp from scartch) ? Are the rights of this mounted/shared directory (`/media/tz/.tezos-node/`) well defined ?